# How can I get total row count of TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

My database consists of table containing more than 1000K records.

I don't want to load entire data in memory, hence I am using TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet.

Currently, I am keeping a counter and iterating the entire ResultSet and incrementing the counter to get the total row count.

Iterating the entire ResultSet takes a lot of time. I don't want to add another count query since my queries are complex and take lot of time to execute.

Is there any efficient way to get the total row count?

Comment: Can you use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` query.  You said you don't want to use one, but that will almost certainly be more efficient than traversing an entire resultset consisting of an entire table.